# How to determine if the GitHub action is running with `debug logging` enabled

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-actions-workflows

I'm writing a Docker-based GitHub action in Python.
I would like to add more verbosity to its output if at some point it fails and the user opts to rerun it with [debug logging enabled](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs#about-re-running-workflows-and-jobs).

So my question is: is it possible to determine it from inside of the action? Maybe some environmental variable is set automatically - or can be set manually in `action.yml`, or something like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That info should be accessible with the `runner` [context variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#runner-context):

[image: runner-context]

so you can access like:

```
${{ runner.debug }}
```

of by condition:

```
  - name: debugging
    if:  runner.debug == '1'
    run: |
```

Comment: This looks like a right answer! I'll approve it as soon as I'll be able to test it out.

Comment: Can also use the `RUNNER_DEBUG` env variable.

Comment: @V.Rubinetti That only works when you explicitly set it in the repo's Actions variables. When you cause a job to rerun with the "Enable debug logging" box checked, `RUNNER_DEBUG` is absent/unchanged.

Comment: Are you sure about that? In my testing it is there when rerunning with "Enable debug logging", and [the docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) seem to suggest it is set automatically by GitHub.

Comment: Maybe you're referring to _"they are not accessible through the `env` context"_. I was referring to using the env variable from within a script being run from a workflow.